# SSH "Connection closed by (ip address) port 22" when a friend tries to connect to me

Tags: ssh

I've been using a Debian machine as a server for a bit and I've never had any issue with connecting to it through SSH from my Windows (10) machine, nor did my friend (Windows 11) (using key authentication), until today, when I restarted my machine.

I can still connect to it, and I can test my port 22 online to see if it's still accessible, however, my friend now cannot make a connection, we tried to make sure his public key didn't change or anything, but it still won't work for him. Whenever he tries

```
ssh fred@(my IP)"/"sftp fred@(my IP)
```

it simply says

```
Connection closed by (my IP) port 22
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: try `ssh -vvv fred@(my IP)` and check the output - also check the router that it is still forwarding the port to the correct (LAN) IP address - perhaps the IP of the Debian machine has changed (if you use DHCP for isntance)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any problems with any of this, I can also connect to server fine with both my PC and laptop, and my port is properly openned, my IP (both public and private for the machine) didn't change either.

Comment: `both my PC and laptop` from inside or outside your LAN? - I'm assuming NATed IPv4 and port forwarding on your router. Anyway, does adding `-v` or `-vv` or `-vvv` give any extra useful information? Also, have you done anything "new" to the Debian server, like add/change the firewall?

Comment: there's also a lot of different potential issues talked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120956/ssh-connection-closed-by-remote-server)

Comment: Since you can access the server and read its logs, you should do so. Does your friend's connection attempt actually reach the server or not? If it does, and the server rejects your friend's connection attempt, it should clearly log the rejection reason. For security reasons, when `sshd` rejects a client's connection, it will **not** tell an unsuccessfully-authenticated client why the connection was terminated.

Comment: Okay, did some more troubleshooting, still not sure what the issue is, we did the `-vvv` thing for both me and him, here's the logs for both [me](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/288821672209940482/1073411551291252826/Working_log.txt) when it's working and for [him](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/288821672209940482/1073411551702298634/Broken_log.txt) which doesn't work.
Also for the last comment by telcoM, I'm not sure what logs I would even be looking for?
Looking with `journalctl -S yesterday -u ssh -x`, I can't even see any connections that he's trying to make.